# What is the name for polynomially solvable optimisation problems?

Tags: terminology, optimization, polynomial-time

An optimisation problem that allows to solve a NPC decision problem through a polynomial reduction is called NP-hard. For these optimisation problems no polynomial algorithm is known.

Symmetrically, is there a standard name for all those optimisation problems for which a polynomial algorithm is known?

Comment: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9556/755

Comment: Thank you but I don't see what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An optimization problem is an example of a function problem: i.e., one where the task is to map some input to some output.  The class of function problems solvable in polynomial time is **FP**. See, for example, the [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:F#fp).

(Note that there is a class [**OptP**](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:O#optp) but that's not the polynomial-time optimization problems. Perhaps confusingly, it's the optimization analogue of **NP**: it's the class of functions that can be defined by taking the maximum out the outputs given by accepting paths of a nondeterministic polynomial-time Turing machine.)

Answer (score 1):

The book [Complexity and Approximation](https://books.google.de/books/about/Complexity_and_Approximation.html?id=Yxxw90d9AuMC) by Ausiello et al. uses the name **PO** for the class of optimization problems that can be solved optimally in polynomial time.